# Decorator casts instance of object in init

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, class-method

I am trying to make a decorator that casts all myt arguments to lists. 
So my code right now is:

from functools import wraps

```
def aslist(func):
    def iflist(a):
        if type(a) is not list:
            return [a]
        else:
            return a
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
        args = map(iflist, args)
        return func(*args, **kwds )
    return wrapper
```

When using it whit functions it works well:

```
@aslist
def functest(a,b,c):
    print(a, b, c)

functest(1,2,[3])
```

But when i try to use it in a class method it casts the *self* to list also:

```
class ClassTest:
@aslist
def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.A = a
    self.B = b
```

and *T = ClassTest(1,2)* fails unless I make the decorator skip the first argument.

Is there a way to make a single decorator work both functions and methods?